# Sencha Tree panel how to placed elements horizontally?

Tags: extjs

I am writing an app where I have to show some structure like family tree. Is it possible to set all children in horizontal position in this example: http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.tree.Panel.1/viewer.html

Something likle:

```
                             Root
                               |
                         child1 ---- child2
                            |
                            |
                         child1.1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Bread Crumbs to make this tree panel work.  You are going to need to use Ext JS5 to use bread crumbs.

Here's a working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/bja